# What should I consider when choosing a filesystem for a personal disk archive / cold storage?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, storage

I have a few TB of media files that never changes and that I need to store safely. Since it's a personal business it's overkill to set up a disk server et cetera, so I use the simple solution of storing the files on harddrives at two different locations. Then, at intervals of a few years, I rewrite the drives to refresh them.

They are now ext4, what are the pros and cons of this?

**What should I consider when choosing a filesystem for storage disks like these?**

Comment: You should consider maturity, data integrity, availability for the target platform, required featureset (e.g. compression), scalability and familiarity with the file system. A file system you know that does the job well is always the better choice before learning something new. Especially when it comes to backups. If ext4 works for you, just keep using it.

Comment: @Christopher That info is only valid for a drive already at end of life. The blog you reference badly misinterpreted some slides. http://www.pcworld.com/article/2925173/debunked-your-ssd-wont-lose-data-if-left-unplugged-after-all.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Ext4 is the standard file system on most Linux distribution. It works, it is safe, and as @Marco said:

> If ext4 works for you, just keep using it

---

#### Choosing a file system

It depends on what are your objectives.

- For a total compatibility across systems, you may choose FAT32 (do not blame me - I think it's a terrible choice).
- NTFS works well on *mostly* all systems, at least in read.
- ReiserFS / Reiser4 (mostly Linux systems) is know to be very fast.
- You may read this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) to see each FS limits and features.

Here are the main features you can think about:

- Journal support (avoid losing data)
- Versioning (switch between files version, like an integrated SVN or GIT support)
- Scalability (extends size; multiples FS over the network ([NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System)))
- Native encryption support
- Drivers (which OS / harware can mount (read/write) the file system ?)
- Design limitations (file name size, maximum size of a file (ex: FAT32 is 2GO))
- Native support for data replication (ex: [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS))

---

#### Ext4 pros:

- Read / write works on every Linux system
- Backward compatible with ext2 and ext3 (mount them as ext4)
- [Journalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system)
- Mature, supported, open-source
- Support SSD trim (in short, increase SSD lifetime)

#### Ext4 cons:

- MacOS and Windows doesn't support Ext4 without additional software(s)
- Recovering deleted files is difficult ([even if a tool exists](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/))